# Laravel unisharp file manager how to disable multi-select

Tags: laravel, file-management

**Laravel unisharp file manager how to disable multi-select**

[image: In Laravel 9 , Unshirp File Managaer I can not disable this button, how I can delete it or disable it, I shoould write script or just change inside lfm config file can somebody give me advice how I can]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First After Install Package

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=lfm_public
```

Then Inside vendor/file-filemanager/js/script.js

```
var myParam = location.search.split('multiple=')[1];//new

if(myParam == 'false'){ //new
        multi_selection_enabled = multi_selection_enabled;//
    }else{
        multi_selection_enabled = !multi_selection_enabled;//here
  }
```

Instead Of  This Code

```
multi_selection_enabled = !multi_selection_enabled
```

Then Inside vendor/file-filemanager/js/stand-alone-button.js

```
 window.open(route_prefix + '?type=' + type+'?&multiple=false',
 'FileManager', 'width=900,height=600');
```

Instead Of  This Code

```
 window.open(route_prefix + '?type=' + type', 'FileManager', 'width=900,height=600');
```

Then Inside Vendor Laravel File Manager src/views/index.blade.php,you should uncomment this script line

```
   <script src="{{ asset('vendor/laravel-filemanager/js/script.js') }}"></script>
```

It helped Me , You can try this .

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

1. Run:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=lfm_view
```

2. Add JS script to resources/views/vendor/laravel-filemanager/index.blade.php(279):

```
<script>
$("#multi_selection_toggle").hide();
</script>
```

[image]